# How to conditionally fill regions using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to draw US map with 2016 Elections Result using R.
The data sets look like this -

```
` >head(data)
       long      lat group order   State subregion Clinton Trump other
1 -87.46201 30.38968     1     1 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
2 -87.48493 30.37249     1     2 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
3 -87.52503 30.37249     1     3 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
4 -87.53076 30.33239     1     4 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
5 -87.57087 30.32665     1     5 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
6 -87.58806 30.32665     1     6 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6`
```

The task is to make a map of state-by-state percentage vote share in each state of the 2016 US presidential election such that if voter percentage of Trump (data$Trump) > Clinton (data$Clinton) it is colored in Red else Blue.

Also, the color strength is proportional to the data value being plotted.

The final map should look like this

[image: what i am supposed to make]

So this is what i have been able to achieve -

```
ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = total, 
                 aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, 
                     fill = ifelse(total$Trump > total$Clinton, 
                                   yes = total$Trump, 
                                   no = total$Clinton)), 
                 color = "black", size = 0.15) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = muted("red"), mid = "white", 
                         midpoint = 50, high = muted("blue"), 
                         limits = c(min(total$Trump), max(total$Clinton)))+
    labs(fill = "TestLabel")
```

which looks something like

[image: what i have made in 5 days]

Can anyone explain me how to go from this gradient scheme to 2 color scheme and "beautify" the map as in the "expected" image?

Note that i am very new to R and Maps using R, so kindly pardon me any obvious mistakes I am making.

Comment: Make a single column to map to fill before you start plotting by subtracting your Clinton and Trump columns. Right now your limits are off from the actual data you're plotting. Getting the AK/HI insets and East Coast pullouts without using a pre-built choropleth package will be a bit of work, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What i understand from creating a different column for |Trump - Clinton| would not give the desired result. I want to use two color scheme- "Blues" for Clinton and "Reds" for Trump filled conditionally (on who has the higher percentage) and shade proportionally (to the respective voter percentage)  rather than a gradient approach.

Comment: You wouldn't want to take the absolute value; the sign tells who won. If you want strictly two-color with no gradient, make a column with that data. Boolean or factor is fine. Just don't try to make the data in the middle of plotting.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate with some code. I am fairly new to this and pardon me but all of this sounds alien to me at times.
I mean dont we already have data for Clinton and Trump in the respective columns?

Comment: It could be as simple as `df$t_win <- df$Trump > df$Clinton`. Currently, the information is there, but not in the format you want to plot it.

Comment: fill = ifelse(total$Trump > total$Clinton, 
                                   yes = total$Trump, 
                                   no = total$Clinton)) essentially does the same thing. But this is not what is required.

Comment: No, it uses the number for Trump or the number for Clinton, but doesn't tell you which is which. Fix your data first, then plot. If you look at it, you'll see the problem.

Comment: did this - 
ggplot(color=factor(who.won))+geom_polygon(data = total, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,fill = ifelse(total$Trump>total$Clinton, yes = total$Trump,no = total$Clinton)), color = "black", size = 0.15)+scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", breaks = brk,trans = "reverse") 

where who.won<-data$Trump>data$Clinton. Doesn't help with 2 coloring. Essentially producing the same map. If you look closely there is some similarity of shading in the "expected" and "generated" maps before. The question is how to make it a 2 color scheme proportional to the numbers.

Comment: Have you looked at RColorBrewer as a means to get your color scheme working? What your looking to do can be done (and likely has already been done by any of the umpzillion people mapping this past election).

Comment: Hello Patrick. Yes I have tried RColorBrewer. I am sure that the solution is in there somewhere but its the lack of my proficiency and an abundance of cryptic methods and arguments that have made the game really hard for me.
Please see the below comment, where i got the colors from diverge_hsv function but its still not working out properly. I have also listed the issues.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following lines of code and modifying the dataframe as suggested by alistaire, i was able to get somewhat close to the objective.

```
>who.won<-as.numeric(total$Trump>total$Clinton)

>total$isTrump<-who.won

>total$votePercent<-ifelse(total$Trump>total$Clinton,yes = total$Trump, no = total$Clinton);

>total$color<-factor(total$isTrump, levels =c(0,1), labels = c("#F79CD4","#0FCFC0"));

>head(total)

  long      lat group order   State subregion Clinton Trump other
1 -87.46201 30.38968     1     1 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
2 -87.48493 30.37249     1     2 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
3 -87.52503 30.37249     1     3 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
4 -87.53076 30.33239     1     4 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
5 -87.57087 30.32665     1     5 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6
6 -87.58806 30.32665     1     6 alabama      <NA>    34.4  62.1   3.6

isTrump votePercent   color
1       1        62.1 #3182BD
2       1        62.1 #3182BD
3       1        62.1 #3182BD
4       1        62.1 #3182BD
5       1        62.1 #3182BD
6       1        62.1 #3182BD

>ggplot()+geom_polygon(data = total, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,fill = as.character(total$color)), color = "black", size = 0.15 )+labs(fill = "Votes")
```

which gives me the following map - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sLhf.png)

Can anyone explain -

1. How to make color transparency proportional to the voting percentage (total$votePercent).
2. How to rename labels of color legend to "Clinton" and "Trump". (Its picks up values from the total$color column which is HEX code color).